# BootstrapV4 and scrollspy

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hidden-field, scrollspy

Can anyone tell me how scrollspy works in bootstrap v4?

**In my navbar**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#getLogin" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="getLogin"></a>
```

**In content**

```
<div id="getLogin" class="hiddenGetPanel">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-9 m-t-lg">
    <div class="FormPanel">
      <div class="FormPanel-head">Login</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do: Click on the `<a>` and scroll to `#getLogin`. It's important that `#getLogin` will show when I use the `<a>` tag.

Comment: where's the Javascript for Scrollspy?

Comment: @Lucky Chingi
Via data attributes or via javascript 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/scrollspy/#usage

Comment: Hi, I've gone ahead and made the English more clear and also slightly improved the indentation of your code. Also, when you reference code or classes/ids within your post, you can use back ticks (usually the upper left corner of your keyboard on the same key as the tilde ~) `to surround a word or words so they are automatically highlighted` when you publish the post. This makes it easy to follow when you reference code snippets. See the editing section for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

remove href="#getLogin" and use data-target="#getLogin" instead of that

see the example here 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy2&stacked=h

Comment: Doesn't work @Shiv Baran Singh

This is for Bootstrap v3. I tried but doesn't work

Comment: sounds good but doesn't scroll.
I check link <a href="#getLogin"></a> - IT WORKS
But My doesnt <a data-toggle="collapse"  href="#getLogin" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="getLogin">

Its problem with data-toggle="collapse"